# Python/Numpy - Turn an array with shape (119,80) into (119,1,80)

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following numpy array. It has shape `(119, 80)`.
I'm burning my neurones trying to figure out how to make its shape turn into `(119, 1, 80)` - that arrangement is apparently necessary to run a SimpleRNN on Keras.

Any idea how can I do that?

Here is the print of the array:

```
[[  0.00000000e+00  -1.00000000e+00   1.03550000e-02 ...,   8.42105263e-01
    6.50000000e+01  -3.98148148e-01]
 [ -1.13600000e-02  -1.07482052e+00  -9.25333333e-03 ...,   4.45783133e-01
    8.30000000e+01  -1.94915254e-01]
 [  4.71300000e-02  -5.14876761e+00   1.63166667e-03 ...,   4.45783133e-01
    8.50000000e+01  -1.94915254e-01]
 ..., 
 [  4.73500000e-02  -1.81092653e+00  -8.54000000e-03 ...,   1.39772727e+00
    2.77000000e+02  -3.43601896e-01]
 [ -6.46000000e-03  -1.13643083e+00   1.06100000e-02 ...,   2.22551929e-01
    2.77000000e+02  -3.43601896e-01]
 [  3.14200000e-02  -5.86377709e+00   1.50850000e-02 ...,   2.22551929e-01
    2.82000000e+02  -2.76699029e-01]]
```

Comment: Use `np.newaxis` : `arr[:,np.newaxis,:]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the shorthand notation `[:,None,:]`

```py
>> import numpy as np
>> a = your_array[:,None,:] # replace `your_array` with the name of your array
>> print a.shape
>> (119, 1, 80)
```

The solution by @Divakar performs just as well:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s "import numpy as np; a = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=(119,80))" "a[:,None,:]" 
    1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.39 usec per loop

@Divakar:
$ python -mtimeit -s "import numpy as np; a = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=(119,80))" "a[:,np.newaxis,:]" 
    1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.45 usec per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for that, however it makes me a random array. I need to keep its original content, but with a different shape.

Comment: Sorry, I should have pointed out that you should replace the random array with the array you are working with. I've updated the code

Comment: Yeah that `None` is just another way or shorthand to put the same thing. Good to see the runtimes!

Comment: You said "The solution by Divakar performs just as well"... if one tries the following from the interactive prompt: `print(np.newaxis)`, they willl understand how it happens and also the small bias in favor of `None`

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you need something like this

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(22).reshape(11,2)
b = a.reshape(11,1,2).swapaxes(0,2)

print a
print b

[[ 0  1]
 [ 2  3]
 [ 4  5]
 [ 6  7]
 [ 8  9]
 [10 11]
 [12 13]
 [14 15]
 [16 17]
 [18 19]
 [20 21]]
[[[ 0  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20]]

 [[ 1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19 21]]]
```